# Getting the error "no match for operator==" working with a 2d array

Tags: arrays, overloading, operator-keyword

I am getting this error when trying to do comparisons with a string array and a char using "==" and "!=". Does this mean I need to do some operator overloading? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do that(or another method) because i'm not too familiar with operator overloading yet.

```
bool legalMove(string list[][7], int row_start, 
    int column_start, int row_end,int column_end)
{
if(list[row_start][column_start] == 'S' && list[row_end][column_end] != ' ')
    {
        if((row_end == row_start + 1 && column_start == column_end) || 
            (row_start == row_end && (column_end == column_start + 1 
                || column_end == column_start  - 1)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It might be because you're trying to compare a `string` to a `char`

Comment: A string is just an array of characters though no? So the list[x][y] at any given time is equal to a char. Or is that incorrect?

Comment: A string is an array of characters, which is different than just a character. You're close in your assumption, but it's actually `list[x][y][z]` that is a character. So you can change your code in two ways. Change your single quotes to double quotes, or check if `list[row_start][column_start][0] == 'S' && list[row_end][column_end][0] != ' '`

Comment: Okay I see. Well in retrospect this was a stupid question lol. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. The important thing is that you learned something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `std::string` to a `char` by using `''`. Try instead

```
if(list[row_start][column_start] == "S" && list[row_end][column_end] != " "){ }
```

If you are using `std::string`, that is a standard-type and you won't be able to overload the `operator==`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for a reference on `std::string`.

Comment: Oh wow... So you can use the assignment operator to set a char into the string but you can't use the comparison operator to check for a char?

Comment: For example in another function i needed to set certain parts of the array to blank spaces so I did this:

    list[0][0] = ' ';
    list[0][1] = ' ';